# Update a listFragment over time

Tags: android, android-listfragment, shoutcast

I'm developing a shoutcast app (stream quality issues with the default MediaPlayer aside) which uses a listFragment to store the song info as the app is active.

As of right now I have a button on that fragment, which I've added an onClickListener to perform an HTTP Get Request through AysncTask. This is working perfectly.
However I obviously don't want to waste the extra space including a button to refresh the list. So I've been trying to implement a timer which can execute the update function for the listFragment no matter which fragment the user is currently viewing.

*The update function does check against duplicates at the top of the list, so I'm not worried about organizing the data.

*As of right now the first fragment which opens has buttons to control a MediaPlayer object, the second is the listFragment.

These are my java files. I'm fairly new to android development so examples of whatever solution would be awesome.

### MainActivity.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
//import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager.WifiLock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    int MediaState = 0; //idle

    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }

        Toast setup = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Setting Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        setup.show();
        //Audio manager
        if(mp==null) //prevent creation of new media player for new instances of the views
        {
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try{
                mp.setAudioSessionId(0);
                mp.setDataSource("http://130.191.35.35:8000");
                mp.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
                mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //playStream(mViewPager);
                        //mp.start();
                        MediaState = 2; //prepared
                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ready to Go", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        t.show();
                    }
                });
                //on info listener not catching any of the info through logcat for live stream skipping audio is due to buffer underruns
                //Should fix by using a stream proxy instead...not sure how to set one up
                mp.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                        if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START) {
                            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Buffering", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            t.show();
                        } else if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END) {
                            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Buffering Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            t.show();
                        } else if (what == 703)
                        {
                            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Problem!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            t.show();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                MediaState = 1; //initialized // or stopped
                mp.prepareAsync();
                MediaState = 6; //MediaPlayer is preparing pick a state that isn't used so nothing works until its prepared
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment;
            if(position==0)
            {
                //returns the main page
                fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
            }
            else
            {  //returns the listFragment
                    fragment = new SecondSectionFragment();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            // Show 2 total pages
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The main screen's fragment
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment{
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public void playStream(View view) {
        if(!mp.isPlaying())
        {
            if(MediaState==2)
            {
                mp.start();
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
                MediaState=3; // Media is now in started state
            }
            if(MediaState==1)
            {
                try
                {
                    mp.prepare();
                    MediaState = 2; // Media is now prepared
                    mp.start();
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
                    MediaState = 3; // Media is now in playing or started state
                }
                catch(IOException ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void pauseStream(View view)
    {
        if(mp.isPlaying())
        {
            mp.pause();
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
            MediaState = 2; // Media is now in paused state
        }
    }
    public void stopStream(View view)
    {
        mp.stop();
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
        MediaState = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        //prevent odd echoing for media player when screen rotates something to do with the activity being destroyed 
    }
}
```

### SecondSectionFragment.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SecondSectionFragment extends ListFragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public SecondSectionFragment() {

    }
    String[] values = new String[] {"Welcome!"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_main_dummy, container, false);
        Button refreshButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                findItem();
            }
        });
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        setupTimer();
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        String text = adapter.getItem(position);
        customToast(text);
    }
    public void customToast(String text)
    {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
    }

    public void addItem(String[] texts)
    {
        for(int t=0;t<texts.length;t++)
        {
            addItem(texts[t]);
        }
    }
    public void addItem(String text)
    {
        String[] prev = new String[values.length];
        prev = values.clone();
        values = new String[prev.length+1];
        values[0]=text;
        for(int i=1;i<values.length;i++)
        {
            values[i]=prev[i-1];
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class HTTPRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet( "http://_____/___.php?q="+Math.random());
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
                int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if(code!=404)
                {
                    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    responseBody = responseBody.replace("</body></html>","");
                    return responseBody;
                }
                return "404 Error";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "Exception";
            }

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String text) {
            if(!text.contains(adapter.getItem(0)))
            {
                addItem(text);
            }
            else
            {
                customToast(adapter.getItem(0));
            }
        }

     }
    public void findItem()
    {
        new HTTPRequest().execute();
    }
    public void setupTimer()
    {
       //Not sure if this would be the correct place to start up a timer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this still valid. I do have such solution for live update.

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        //  DO here something like your  findItem()
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, TIMEOUT);
    }
};

 public void setupTimer() {
    if (mHandler != null) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, TIMEOUT);
    }
}
```

call your setupTimer() from onResume()
in your onPause()  add

```
    if (mHandler != null) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for an example using a runnable, I was having difficulty with those. Although I changed my program around to avoid timers, I found a way of triggering functions with implementables and let the tab update itself when viewed. Not ideal when the list is supposed to be up to date, I'll have to go back and add that in. It'll drastically reduce the lag when switching views for me.